# How can I use different point types in the same line in a 2D gnuplot graph?

Tags: gnuplot, linestyle

I'm need to plot one line in which for instance some points may be red circles and some points may be blue circles. Another case is to have in the same line some points represented as filled circles and some points as empty circles. I'd like to know if there's any way to explicitly define which point type should be used for each point or group (interval) of points on the same line.

Please consider a simple dataset such as

1 1.59
2 0.39
3 0.88
4 1.23
5 1.00

In this case I need to use filled cicles for points (3,0.88) and (4,1.23) and use empty circles for the remaining ones.

Here comes an example of what I'd like to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMwfV.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter? Nobody here is going to solve your problem for you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I don't see the problem with this question, seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with a conditional plot. You need to plot the same file twice: once requiring that the points be between 3 and 4 and the rest:

```
plot "data" using 1:($1 >= 3 && $1 <= 4 ? $2 : 1/0) pt 1, \
"data" using 1:($1 >= 3 && $1 <= 4 ? 1/0 : $2) pt 2
```

The first plot plots column 2 if the value in column 1 is between 3 and 4 (inclusive) and second plot does the opposite, each plot uses a different point type, as requested:

[image]

The number following `pt` changes the point style.